# Summarize datatable by group based on nrows of other column

Tags: r, data.table, group-summaries

I know that this command below will summarize my table by adding the population by group and dividing it by the number of rows of each group.

```
dt[, .(pop=sum(pop_ct)/sum(.N)), , by=.(geoid)]
```

What I want to do, however, is to dived the summed population by the **number of rows of another column** *in each group*. something like this:

```
dt[, .(pop=sum(pop_ct)/ nrow(dt$geoid) ), , by=.(geoid)]
```

The point here is that the `geoid` `id6` and `id7` are subregions of `ct` `E1010`, so the population of `id6` and `id7` should be an equal proportion of the population of the larger area `E1010` in which they are contained.

## Expected result

Using the reproducible example bellow, this is the result I would like to get to:

```
>    geoid pop
> 1:   id1  47
> 2:   id2  35
> 3:   id3  10
> 4:   id5  30
> 5:   id4  10
> 6:   id6  10
> 7:   id7  10
```

## Reproducible example

```
dt <- data.table(
  udh = LETTERS[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5)],
  ct = c('A000','A111','A222','A333','B444','B555','C666','C777','C888','D999','E1010','E1010'),
  pop_udh = c(40,40,40,40,30,30,45,45,45,17,20,20),
  pop_ct = c(20,10,8,2,25,5,5,30,10,17,20,20),
  poor_prop_udh = c(10,10,10,10,5,5,8,8,8,7,9,9),
  geoid = c('id1','id2','id2','id1','id1','id3','id3','id5','id4','id2','id6','id7'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pre calculate the sizes of `ct` and the divide accordingly, for example

```
dt[, N := .N, by = ct
   ][, .(pop = sum(pop_ct)/N[1L]), by = geoid]
#    geoid pop
# 1:   id1  47
# 2:   id2  35
# 3:   id3  10
# 4:   id5  30
# 5:   id4  10
# 6:   id6  10
# 7:   id7  10
```